# How do I use ARRAYFORMULA, IF, and VLOOKUP in a formula to populate down the column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to create an arrayformula that will populate down the column in COL N.

I need it to find the purchaser name if the posted date and cost match on another list (See the second image).
[image]

[image]

I know that the costs in the first picture dont show up in the second, but they do further down the list.

So far, my formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(VLOOKUP(C3:C,'X3'!B2:B,1,0)=C3:C,VLOOKUP(A3:A,'X3'!A2:B,1,0)=A3:A),VLOOKUP(A3:A,'X3'!A2:E,4,0)))
```

however this doesn't work. I can't figure out how to use an arrayformula in conjunction with IF and VLOOKUP.

Comment: please read the tags you are choosing to ensure they apply.  The Google-Sheets tag specifically states: `Do NOT use with [excel]`  Spamming tags leads to answers that will not work for your problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a dummy sheet file with data for replication. This way, the community will be able to provide an accurate answer to your post. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're trying to find a match between multiple conditions, I suggest you try with FILTER. I'm not sure what column are you trying to retrieve, I think it's D, if not change it:

```
=FILTER('X3'!D2:D,'X3'!B2:B=C3,DATEVALUE('X3'!A2:A)=A3)
```

To use it as ARRAYFORMULA you could use MAP:

```
=MAP(A3:A,C3:C,LAMBDA(da,cost,IF(da="","",IFNA(FILTER('X3'!D2:D,'X3'!B2:B=da,DATEVALUE('X3'!A2:A)=cost)))))
```

Let me know if it's useful!

Comment: Thanks! that MAP works great, you just had da and cost flipped in the final filter there, but thats ok because it made me have to go figure out why it didn't work and i learned some things. thanks!

Comment: Would you have a suggestion on how to modify the MAP formula so the date would match if the date falls between 3 days in either direction of the date?

Comment: Oh, you're right, hehe. Try with this for the range of dates: `=MAP(A3:A,C3:C,LAMBDA(da,cost,IF(da="","",IFNA(FILTER('X3'!D2:D,'X3'!B2:B=cost,DATEVALUE('X3'!A2:A)>=(da-3),DATEVALUE('X3'!A2:A)<=(da+3))))))`